# Column color and l3colors

Tags: tables, color, latex3, xparse

Consider the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{l3color}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{l3draw}

\definecolor{sampleredexpl}{RGB}{21,71,158}
%\ExplSyntaxOn
% \color_set:nnn {sampleredexpl} {RGB} {21,71,158}
%\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{sampleredexpl!20}}c|}
\hline
$t$ (min)\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Note that the code above compiles without error. Now consider I want to use `l3draw` to create diagrams and define a color using `\color_set:nnn {sampleredexpl} {RGB} {21,71,158}`. Using this color elsewhere works fine, but if I want to use it in table columns I cannot.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{l3draw}


\ExplSyntaxOn
 \color_set:nnn {sampleredexpl} {RGB} {21,71,158}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{sampleredexpl!20}}c|}
\hline
$t$ (min)\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

does not compile. I presume that colors using the command `\columncolor{@}` has to be defined using `\definecolor{@}{@}{@}`. I tried loading the `colortbl` package along with `l3draw` but still it does not respect the color definition using `l3color`.

Is it possible for LaTeX to respect either definition? That is, can I use a well-defined color in `l3` syntax to color the column. I would guess it should be something like a global color.

Comment: well it is certainly possible, but it hasn't been done yet.

Comment: This would require Joseph and I to talk to each other, that would never do:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wonder why.:)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

`colortbl` makes the coloured panel with `\color` but it expects that that command is related to the color definition command used to define the color. You can make its wish come true by defining `\color` to be `\color_select:n`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{l3draw}


\ExplSyntaxOn
 \color_set:nnn {sampleredexpl} {RGB} {21,71,158}
 \RenewDocumentCommand\color{om}{\color_select:n{#2}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{sampleredexpl!20}}c|}
\hline
$t$ (min)\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was wondering how `\columncolor` is defined and noticed `l3` has no form of array construct. Originally, my thought was to look at its definition and through reconstruct see if it is possible to do it natively in `l3`.

Comment: @azetina it is just  (more or less) `\color{..}\rule{..}{..}` where size of the rule is the size of the table cell background so you just need a normal document level color command but l3color currently only provides a programming layer interface. Main thing missing here is using the optional argument `\color[rgb]{1,0,0}` should use `\color_select:nn{rgb}{1,0,0}` I may add that later.